# How to maximise an function in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a function T which I'm wanting to maximise:

T = (B((A + 1.646) + 0.583 w) + 311)((1 + ((R + 0.553) + 0.0389 x)((D) + 0.0389 y)

with the constraints

w + x + y + z = 25
w >= 0
x >= 0
y >= 0
z >= 0

B, A, R, D are all constants.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183168/Solving-optimization-problems-with-Microsoft-Solve

Comment: There is no z in T.

Comment: First step I would take is simplify the formula by combining your constants. The new form is `(a + b * W) * (c + d * Y + e * X + f * X * Y)`, `W + X + Y = 25, W >= 0, X >= 0, Y >= 0`. I omit z because so do you